# send modified data with ncclient from router, how it works ?

Tags: python, xml, config, router, xml.etree

I want to get data from a router, modify it and send the modified data to the router. This is how I do it. I can get the running data from my router and change the name of a device for example in here. But when I want to send it back to the router I got a lot of error.

```
import sys
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from ncclient import manager

with manager.connect(host="192.168.X.X", port=2022, username="admin", password="admin", hostkey_verify=False, allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False) as m:
    first = m.get_config('running')

root = ET.fromstring(str(first))
file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
file.write(str(first))
for data in root.findall("{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:x:base:1.0}data"):
    for devices in data.findall("{http://tail-f.com/ns/x}devices"):
        for device in devices.findall("{http://tail-f.com/ns/x}device"):
            for name in device.findall("{http://tail-f.com/ns/x}name"):
                new_name= "NameDevice"
                name.text = (str(new_name))
                final = data
with manager.connect(host="192.168.x.x", port=2022, username="admin", password="admin", hostkey_verify=False, allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False) as m:
    c = m.get_config(source='running').data_xml
    m.edit_config(target='running', config=str(final))
```

When I put this str(final) I get in return:

```
XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 1, column 10
```

But I tried a lot of different thing, I even try to send it the variable c, who I think is normally the same as my variable first. But I got error too like :

```
XMLError: Element [{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:x:base:1.0}data] does not meet requirement
```

I think I don't understand how it works and I would like someone to explain it to me. Thank you.